# How to divide an n-dimensional array by an integer value?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 5X5 matrix with the data

```
array([[38170, 218, 454, 2, 0],
       [2813, 4647, 0 , 0, 0],
       [1746, 0, 675, 0, 0],
       [2862, 0 , 0, 23, 0],
       [64, 0, 0, 0, 3]])
```

How do I reduce the values in each element by a factor of 4 (with values returning as float type and not rounded figures) i.e. divide each element in the array by 4?

I have tried

```
np.ndarray.div__mod__(conf_mat, 4, /)
```

conf_mat is the variable storing the 5X5 array.

Comment: Use `4.0` or `numpy.true_divide`.

Comment: What was wrong with `conf_mat / 4`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try `conf_mat / 4` or `conf_mat * .25`.